# Write a Ninject test with mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I am really new to ninject and testing too.

I have an mvc4 application that I want to start writing tests for. (Yes I know I am meant to write them as I go:) )

Within my NinjectWebCommon

```
  private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        RegisterServices(kernel);
        return kernel;
    }

    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IConsumerRepository>().To<ConsumerRepository>();
    }
```

I have written everything in repository's within my application for example I have

```
public interface IConsumerRepository
{
    ConsumerModel GetConsumerByUserId(Guid userId);
}
public ConsumerModel GetConsumerByUserId(Guid userId)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ConsumerInfo"] == null)
        {
            var data = RestSharperHelper.GetById<ConsumerModel>("id", userId, ApiEndPointConstants.GetConsumerById);
            LogMessage(data.UserName);
            HttpContext.Current.Session["ConsumerInfo"] = data;
            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            return (ConsumerModel)HttpContext.Current.Session["ConsumerInfo"];
        }
    }
```

Whats the best way for me to write a test to check that a ConsumerModel is returned from web applications repository? I want it be flexible as in time I want to write more complicated tests and provide a mock ConsumerModel instead of calling the api like the above everytime

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: This method cannot be unit tested in isolation as it depends on too many static methods such as `RestSharperHelper.GetById` and `HttpContext.Current`. You will have to introduce abstractions for them if you want to be able to unit test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **MVCContrib TestHelper** might help.  It'll help you unit test your controller actions and will also initialise all those parts like `HttpContext` and `Session`:

http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper